# Writing a Top Score to a data file

Tags: python, file, logging

I am trying to create a file that will hold just one number; the highscore to a game I am writing.

I have

```
f = open('hisc.txt', 'r+')
```

and

```
f.write(str(topScore))
```

What I want to know how to do is to:

- Erase the entire file
- Get the number in the file and make it a variable in the game
- Check if the topScore is higher than the number in the file, and if so, replace it

Comment: Your algorithm cannot begin with "erase the entire file" and then "get the number in the file". Otherwise it seems fine; go ahead and implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's my preference, but I am much more used to the idiom in which on initialization, you do

```
f = open('hisc.txt','r')
# do some exception handling so if the file is empty, hiScore is 0 unless you wanted to start with a default higher than 0
hiScore = int(f.read())
f.close()
```

And then at the end of the game:

```
if myScore > hiScore:
   f = open('hisc.txt', 'w')
   f.write(str(myScore))
   f.close()
```

Comment: Will this get rid of any numbers that are previously there?

Comment: Note that this does assume only one instance of the game is running at a time; otherwise you would need to do some sort of flocking to guarantee that if person 1 and 2 beat the high score at about the same time and 1 has a higher score than 2 but 2 saves his score later, they don't have an issue

Comment: Yes, if you open the file for 'w'riting instead of 'r'eading or 'a'ppending, it will overwrite whatever was in that file. For a single integer value, this isn't normally an issue; be aware if you're writing more data this does mean that if you program dies while it's partially through your writes, you will have a potential corrupted file.

Comment: Note that I should have used the with mechanism Robᵩ used (basically, doing with will guarantee that the f.close gets called and therefore the code is cleaner than mine)

Answer (score 1):

> *Erase the entire file*

```
with open('hisc.txt', 'w'):
    pass
```

> *Get the number in the file and make it a variable in the game*

```
with open('hisc.txt', 'r') as f:
    highScore = int(f.readline())
```

> *Check if the topScore is higher than the number in the file*

```
if myScore > highScore:
```

> *and if so, replace it*

```
if myScore > highScore:
    with open('hisc.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(myScore))
```

Putting it all together:

```
# UNTESTED
def UpdateScoreFile(myScore):
    '''Write myScore in the record books, but only if I've earned it'''
    with open('hisc.txt', 'r') as f:
        highScore = int(f.readline())
    # RACE CONDITION! What if somebody else, with a higher score than ours
    # runs UpdateScoreFile() right now?
    if myScore > highScore:
        with open('hisc.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(myScore))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('hisc.txt', 'w')
f.write('10') # first score
f.close()


highscore = 25 #new highscore

# Open to read and try to parse
f = open('hisc.txt', 'r+')
try:
    high = int(f.read())
except:
    high = 0

# do the check
if highscore > high:
    high = highscore

f.close()

# open to erase and write again
f = open('hisc.txt', 'w')
f.write(str(high))
f.close()

# test
print open('hisc.txt').read()
# prints '25'
```